# Why do we confine ourselves to static ‘thing’ logic when we are dealing formally with time, which is dynamic?

Tags: logic, time

All ‘temporal’ logic statements are expressed in solely static terms that can be compared to static reference phrases or related to the number line and evaluated with arithmetic.

For example, suppose you asked a computer and a human to determine in which order two events occurred, given the occurrence of the two events (you raised one hand and then the other):

1. The human would be able to answer immediately and directly, having an innate sense of time.
2. The computer would not be able to answer directly, but would have to first determine the clock time at which each of the two events occurred (place them on a linear, or space-domain, scale of time), then check that against which rule the local time runs upon (ascending or descending numbers) in order to infer the order in which the events occurred. In the case of ascending clock numbers, the lower numbered event would be the earlier one (and the other later). In the case of descending clock numbers, the higher numbered event would be the earlier one (and the other later).

Comment: Intriguingly, you suggest the human "...would be able to answer instantly..." even though science has shown it is not possible for a human to react to a stimulus in less than 100ms (the period it takes someone with olympic grade reflexes to respond to a light turning on by pressing a button).  In fact, there are many cases where humans are remarkably *bad* at using their innate sense of time.  We have great trouble grappling with causality at high speeds.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps a better word is 'immediately.' Humans would not have to look up references, but would be able to respond immediately upon receiving the stimului. Not so computers, which need a series of other operations before the results can be inferred and output. Speed of response is not the  meaningful metric, in this instance, but sophisticated logical operations. Computers have no sense of time, but must be informed about time through static, or 'spatial' representations. Temporal sense is inherent in living entities.

Comment: Actually, we design computers to respond immediately as well.  However, they are typically high speed circuits, as opposed to general purpose circuitry.  A particular formulation known as NL might be worth researching, for it explicitly targeted such response times.  It may be worth pondering whether human sensations of time might have a similar gradiated approach.  After all, we do wish people happy birthday, and we can organize them chronologically.

Comment: To which 'NL' do you refer? I may be highly interested. Do you have a reference, or the name (written out)?

Comment: Process philosophy deals with the dynamic aspect of time. Whitehead for example. Also Heidegger deals with 'being' as a dynamical thing. Henri Bergson is another.

Comment: Aristotle considered the representation of time, then Boole. Both assumed that static representation would suffice. All the modern tools, however, are static. Henri Bergson asked, in Time and Free Will (1889), “Where is the ‘becoming’?” One hundred seventeen years later, Dr. Lee Smolin in The Trouble With Physics (2006) queried, “How can we represent time without turning it into space?”

Comment: The ancient philosophers held that logical formulations, especially premises, were to be kept unchanged (otherwise how could conclusions remain valid?). That concept has been maintained to modern times, although now it is evident that change is the only constant. There is, however, no “logic of change” currently accepted. Instead, change is reckoned through comparison of one static frame to another and is restricted to static logic or arithmetical processes, which are the only methods available, if limited to computation.

Comment: @Cort Ammon “the troublesome intuitive concepts” are troublesome only because no one has simplified the approach. Ordinary logic is static from ancient times to now. All machinations via computation are necessarily limited to the static and the discrete. Another option is required with which to handle the continuous aspects of our universe. Do you have a reference for ‘NL’?

Comment: @CharlesMoeller Blast, I looked for a reference, but could not find it.  I thought it was called "Natural Logic," but my google searches failed me.  However, from your comments on my answer, it looks like NL is not what you are looking for.  It avoids the example of how you describe computers approaching time, but does not actually leave the concept of linear time.

Comment: I know of a 'NL' or Natural Logic (a nick name). Its full name is Natural Logic of Space and Time. My view of time is linear and parallel-concurrent a la Minkowski's world lines. Googling things now vs. even a couple of years ago is vastly different, as there is an ongoing data-explosion!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question. In the first place, logic isn't particularly about "things" as opposed to say "relations" including relations in time like before/after. However, I think what the OP is getting at is that statements in formal logic often look "tenseless", i.e. like they are eternal, timeless statements.

I think OP is inferring from the fact that statements of first-order logic (the kind we learn in the intro logic class) are tenseless that therefore logic has no ability to represent time. That inference isn't right though.

Here are three ways in which time can be represented logically:

- First, in ordinary first-order logic, we can simply add time as a parameter to our predicates. So to say "x is an F at time t" we write: F(x,t) instead of just F(x).
- Second, we can extend first-order logic by adding *modal operators*. So let 'FUTURE(phi)' be an operator that takes the sentence phi and says that that sentence will be true in the future. We can now write "x will be F" as 'FUTURE(F(x))'. This approach to time and tense is widely studied *I think* in contemporary linguistics.
- Third, we can also represent time in logic by allowing truth values of our propositions to change. This is called dynamic logic and it can be used to represent the flow of information through a complex machine which changes through a series of different states. Unsurprisingly, dynamic logic is of interest to computer scientists and AI researchers.

Comment: Those representations confirm my original statement

Comment: @CharlesMoeller Then I don't at all understand what your question is supposed to be. Can you clarify it? Can you give us a definition like " x is 'static' if and only if . . ." ? What makes you think humans are actually doing anything different at all here? The fact that you can't introspectively determine how your mind represents time doesn't mean that your mind doesn't represent it pretty much the way a computer does. (That's more or less the point of cognitive science.)

Comment: A computer is a machine that is special-built to manage symbols. That is all a computer can actually do. Anything else a computer may look like it is doing is a human-designed routine and interpretation of symbol management. You may say that humans manage symbols too. Yes, humans manage symbols, but that is only one of the multitude of things humans can do, while it is the single and only function that is necessary and sufficient for computing. See Searle’s Chinese Room Argument: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/chinese-room/

Comment: Time is perceived and identified by the duration between occurrences. Time has the ability to accept any conditions and events, without regard to when they occur. There are no favored or forbidden moments or durations. The occurrence, duration, and sequence of events are determined solely by the actions and reactions of the objects that create them. Time is without intrinsic feature, except for the events and conditions it contains. Time is therefore assumed to be non-discrete and continuous. Simply put, time is the sequence of events.

Comment: I understand the chinese room argument, but I don't understand any of the claims about time in the comment that follow, nor do I see why we should think they are true. What would it be for time to "accept" a condition? Suppose I accept time is just a relation of sequences of events. Why would it follow that it is continuous rather than discrete? (I have no problem thinking of time as continuous, I just don't see how this follows) Suppose I accept that time is continuous, why would it follow it isn't representable symbolically, and hence computable? After all, we can compute continuous things.

Comment: Laying the groundwork for discourse on my question. Time is not created. It is what we find as one of the features of our universe. Time is the canvas that accepts all events, as space is the canvas that accepts all matter and energy. Time is continuous because it accepts both the continuous and the discrete. (A discrete construction, like computation, can not accept a continuous function.) Time is representable, in either continuous or discrete forms. The discrete is computable, but the continuous isn't. We can only ‘compute’ the continuous through piecewise (discrete) approximations.

Comment: Logic is about the relationships between things or states, labels about things, or symbols that represent things. We go to lots of trouble to exclude time from logic: 
1. All logical operations are performed within the static timeless zone between clock pulses or instructions,
2. If there is a time in the expression, it is not real, ongoing time, but a static label, as ‘noon’
3. All necessary temporal cues and referents are static ‘values’ that are available (in memory) for retrieval and comparison. 
In short, ongoing time introduces the possibility of change, which is not allowed.

Comment: @CharlesMoeller Continuous quantities certainly are computable, and not just as piecewise approximations. That's the neat thing about mathematica and maple and other software packages that can perform symbolic integration: they can actually perform the exact operations on real numbers like pi. For an example, go to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e+%5E+(i+*+pi)  and see that the program correctly evaluates the expression to "-1".

Comment: I also think the three points you make are false. 1. logical operations aren't defined in reference to clocks. 2. why suppose that "12pm" isn't a time just because it's a (logical) constant. 3. I don't understand at all. What's "memory" supposed to mean here and what's it got to do with precluding change? The point of having computer memory is that you can *alter* the contents of the memory, no?

Comment: Rereading your comments, I think I'm starting to see a distinction that might be helpful. You seem to be confusing logic, the branch of mathematics, with computer engineering. Logic doesn't use terms like "clock" "memory" or whatever and it doesn't need them. Computer engineers trying to figure out how to build a machine that can evaluate logical expressions do. I'm starting to think your questions are more strictly about properties of computer systems than about logic systems. Logic, as I've tried to suggest above, has lots of ways of referring to time.

Comment: Good viewpoint! For useful work (ex theory in written form) we have mechanized and computerized logic. But present day logic, even while practiced at blinding speed in computers, is the same kind as in ancient times. Aristotle’s logic, Boole’s logic, and computer logic are all contemporaneous (at one and the same time) logics. Whether in stone, on papyrus, tablet, or performed in a computer chip, contemporaneous logic is static logic. Time is essentially frozen while the logic operations are thought about and discussed, or actually performed.

Comment: If software “evaluates the expression,” it is ‘managing discrete symbols,’ as said.  Computers can not handle physical process variables in real time (without using discrete contemporaneous operations) simply because current thought processes and the hardware used for implementation is limited to those kinds of operations.  (I can, however, demonstrate *non-contemporaneous logic elements* that are able to handle physical process events as they occur in continuous time.) For one example, see <https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=non-contemporaneous+logic+element>

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer may be that the purpose of "formal" dealings with times is to explicitly remove the troublesome intuitive concepts which lead to great deals of disagreement regarding time.  Consider that you say:

> The human would be able to answer instantly and directly, having an innate sense of time.

You make this statement axiomatically.  It's an assumption.  You assume humans can do this.  Many have assumed similar.  The result tends to cause all sorts of issues.  The famous issue of the grandfather paradox is one example.  An attempt to apply human intuition to a rather nuanced problem typically results in all sorts of problems, hence why it is considered a paradox.  A formal approach to time is typically used to break this up.

There are countless examples of where the human innate sense of time breaks down.  Consider the famous [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).

> The ship wherein Theseus and the youth of Athens returned from Crete
>   had thirty oars, and was preserved by the Athenians down even to the
>   time of Demetrius Phalereus, for they took away the old planks as they
>   decayed, putting in new and stronger timber in their places, in so
>   much that this ship became a standing example among the philosophers,
>   for the logical question of things that grow; one side holding that
>   the ship remained the same, and the other contending that it was not
>   the same.

The result of this was the classification of two extreme views on time, the endurable point of view which roughly models time as a series of frames like a movie, and the perdurable point of view which explores objects as things in "4 space," 3 dimensions plus time.  We do not, in fact, confine ourselves to static thinking, unless we choose to limit ourselves to only using the endurable point of view.

The innate sense of time is also made far more complicated by scientific discoveries about how the mind work.  It is becoming harder and harder to treat our perception as metaphysical hocus pocus; we are having to come to grips with the physical processes that appear to make the universe work.  One key reality is that a surprisingly large amount of what we do can be modeled using local equilibrium thermodynamics, where the "relaxation rate" of small scale events is so much faster than the larger scale events we care about that we can handwave them away as error terms.  Only a small portion of physics calls for non-equilibirum thermodynamics to achieve *acceptably* accurate predictive results.  For systems where local equilibrium thermodynamics is sufficient, modeling time as a series of snapshots is actually a very effective approach.  It is so effective, in fact, that in a surprisingly large number of cases people don't even realize they are making an assumption when they fall into the endurable point of view.

Of course, if you look at a large portion of the literature, the endurable approach *is* popular.  Personally I believe that its because the questions that arise from the perdurable point of view are troublesome.  In many cases, we want answers, so we turn to the more tractable endurable approach.

You will find a different focus in Eastern literature.  Much of Eastern philosophy revolves around the Dao, which is much more reasonably modeled as a dynamic perdurable entity rather than an endurable series of frames.  The Dao is ever changing, in their philosophies.  As a result, they tend more towards perdurable ways of thinking.  The result is that they require many concepts, such as Chi and the Dao, which seem strange to Westerners because they, with a typically endurable mindset, do not fully understand why the concepts are useful to the Eastern philosophers.

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
One problem with the endurable, or frame, model of time in process control computers is the vast number of frames that must be processed and result in no operation in a controller that must respond rapidly, but seldom. These cases are typical for safety-, or time-critical functions that almost never occur. Competition for those resources by other linear-sequential processes results in higher clock rates. Wasteful, I say. My OP aimed to show the limitations of static and linear-sequential (thing) logic operation and then to suggest that perhaps there is an alternative.

Comment: @CharlesMoeller I think people are open to an alternative, but the real question is "what?"  You specifically call out the innate sense of time living creatures have, but what do we actually want to learn from this innate sense? From research, that innate sense is far from perfect.  FAR from perfect.  And the parts that are rather close to perfect are well modeled by the existing linear time approaches.  It would help to identify the cases where we look to learn from living creatures.  For example, we seem to be remarkably good at interacting with chaotic systems like inverted pendulums...

Comment: ... for the quality of the sensory and motor control we have.  Computers can sense much faster, and move much more precisely, and yet dealing with these chaotic systems is recognized as a challenge for them.

Comment: As for efficiency, and avoiding waste, I agree there is a valued goal there, and I think the industry agrees.  For example, if you look at the world of multithreaded programming, we used to rely entirely on exclusion to generate a program flow that could have been single threaded (linear time).  That was found to be inefficient.  Modern atomic operations are designed to permit scenarios that cannot be described in a linear single threaded way.  You have to approach time as a lattice to capture the exact behavior of atomic operations.  Atomic operations, interrupts, vector clocks...

Comment: ... these are constructs that have been invented because people recognized the limits of a linear approach to time.  At the same time, every one of them has a toe hold in linear time, even if it's just a mathematical limit, because we have found linear time to be mindbogglingly effective at describing things.

Comment: What we need is certainly not any more complexity! (more software can not cure software) What we need is a parallel-concurrent logic that operates in continuous time. The place where confusion arises is between data and events. Both are information, but through familiarity with, and the ubiquitousness of, computing, both are translated into symbols. Wrong! Data can be symbols, quite right. But events can be treated in continuous time, as they should be, in order to bypass the complexities of event to data, storage and retrieval, static operations and eventually output to real-time.

Comment: What we can learn from the human sense of time is that it is naturally continuous. Frame-based operations are artificial. We should probably lean away from the artificial and toward the natural for anything that is safety-, time-, or mission-critical. Yes, our senses are far from perfect, but you must admit they have taken us to the present moment. (survived and thrived)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37599/discussion-between-charles-moeller-and-cort-ammon).